# H2 Database multiple connections

Tags: h2

I have the following issue:
Two instances of an application on two different systems should share a small database.
The main problem is that both systems can only exchange data through a network-folder.
I don't have the possibilty to setup a database-server somewhere.

Is it possible to place a H2 database on the network-folder and let both instances connect to the database (also concurrently)?

I could connect with both instances to the db using the embedded mode if I disable the file-locking, right?
The instances can perfom either READ or INSERT operations on the db. Do I risk data corruptions using multiple concurrent embedded connections?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As the documentation says; ( http://h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode
)

> Multiple processes can access the same database without having to start the server manually. To do that, append ;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE to the database URL. You can use the same database URL independent of whether the database is already open or not. This feature doesn't work with in-memory databases.

```
// Application 1:
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:/data/test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE");

// Application 2:
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:/data/test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE");
```

Answer (score 2):

[From H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_file_locking):

> It is also possible to open the database without file locking; in this
>   case it is up to the application to protect the database files.
>   Failing to do so will result in a corrupted database.

I think that if your application use always the same configuration (shared file database on network folder), you need to create an application layer that manages concurrency

Comment: i read this already, but I also read something about table level locking support. Am I correct that table locking is only used in client/server mode? For multiple embedded connections, implementing my own locking mechanism is the only option?

Comment: if you can run a server, it manages the table level locking. But without it, you have to implement a your own mechanism

Comment: Actually, table level locks are used by default even in the embedded and in-memory mode, if you open more than one connection to the database (within the same process).

Comment: I downvoted this answer because the correct answer imho is: yes it is possible to put a H2 database on the network-folder and let both instances connect to the database using the "auto_server" option of h2 databse.