# Why even when I close the EntityManager I can´t manipulate the database?

Tags: java, hibernate

I create the `EntityManager`, begin a transaction, commit it, then I close the `EntityManager`. Why can't I manipulate the database while my app is running (even after close the `EntityManager` connection `em.close();` ) ?

```
    public void create(Product product) {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(product);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: actually  `EntityManager` should be opened to manipulate database.... have you added `@Transactional` to methods making database operations? Are you using plain Java or hibernate?

Comment: please don't add code at comments, edit your question

Comment: To clarify: You cannot manipulate the database *outside of your app*, i.e. bypassing the internal connection pool?

Comment: @dhke, Affirm..That´s it

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*manipulate the database*"? If you are connecting to a proper database _server_ you should be be able to run DML statements against that even while your application is running. Which DBMS are you using? And how do you connect?

Comment: I´m using H2 database, and i´m connecting to it via JPA driver inside the app. But I can´t access the database via browser console to test if my app added the data to the fields when my app GUI is opened (even when I call `EntityManager.close()`.

Comment: @Jordi, I´m using persistence API, EclipseLink 2.1

Comment: Database may be already in use: null. Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-188] 90020/90020

Comment: Where do you get the `EntityManager` from? More precisely, can you obtain the corresponding `EntityManagerFactory`? That one also has a `.close()` method that might actually do more in the direction of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `auto_server=true` to the line
`<property "javax.persistence.jdbc.url"value="jdbc:h2:C:/Users/Bruno/protocol_tracker;auto_server=true"/>` in the persistence.xml file and "voilà"..It works

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with single-user databases. I suspect that the issue is that the Entity Manager is using a JDBC connection taken from a connection pool and so even though the Entity Manager is closed the connection remains open, having been returned to the pool for future use.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401991/h2-database-multiple-connections) suggests some possibilities to allow multiple access to H2.

Alternatively, how about downloading something like MySQL?