# How to enable concurrent db connection for local server in guidewire

Tags: guidewire

trying to enable concurrent db connections
E.g - DB1, Local machine id-1
DB1, local machine id-2
I am trying to use same db connections from multiple systems and configured the same db under jdbc-url property in database-config.xml file

but i am getting below errors :
**INFO** Starting single-node cluster channel
**INFO** Members joined the cluster: [Local machine id 2]   **NOTE :Server of Local machine with id 1 is up **
**ERROR** Cluster members are still active : [Local machine id 1]
**WARN** Cannot start cluster channel, stopping the channel
An exception was thrown, Billing Center unable to start
GW Lifecycle Exception
Caused by GWConfigurationException: **Other servers are found active, but the clustering is disabled.**

Few things missed in initial query:

1. We are using SQL DB (version 14.0.3) hosted on a server, and multiple people are trying to connect to this db from their local studio.
2. we are using GW Version 10.0.2 (Self-managed)

Answer (score 2):

The most rubust way to do this would be to switch to using PostgreSQL for your local DB, which doesn't have the same constraints as the ootb H2 configuration.  This is a relatively straightforward change but do use the correct version of PostgreSQL (12.6 or later minor versions, I believe).  If you choose this option and hit issues please add a comment and I will attempt to help further.

For staying with H2, there is a switch you can add to the H2 jdbc connect string - append ;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE to the database URL -  as shown in this posting:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27129276/22770332

One of these approaches should help, but be aware that for cloud deployments, using this configuration won't work for accessing other databases.  Your question is a little abstract to know your exact use cases so I'm adding this just to make sure you understand the limitations of this approach.

Comment: Hi Martin, i forgot to add below things in my original post.
1. We are using SQL DB (version 14.0.3) hosted on a server, and multiple people are trying to connect to this db from their local studio.
2. we are using GW Version 10.0.2 (Self-managed)

Comment: Assumptions : We will be using same code bases in all the studios where we're trying this functionality. Also we will prevent doing any data model upgrades in those code bases since if we do it wil trigger db upgrades and the whole thing might be a complete mess.

Comment: Oh, this is a very different situation than I assumed.  No, you cannot connect multiple independent instances to one db regardless of your restrictions.  You will incur concurrent data change exceptions and possible data corruption.  You might be able to make this work if each instance has a separate schema and login, but that defeats the purpose of sharing the resources in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In the on-premise versions of InsuranceSuite there is a ClusteringEnabled parameter in the config.xml that must be true for the environment variable you are running your application on. See below.

```
<!-- Is clustering enabled?
       Shared with CM
  -->
  <param name="ClusteringEnabled" value="false"/>
  <param name="ClusteringEnabled" value="false" env="local_sql"/>
```

Comment: tried ClusteringEnabled=true in config.xml but got following error : Full upgrade cannot proceed because the process must be enabled first. Please review the documentation.

Comment: With a clustered environment you need to set the auto-upgrade flag before shutting down or when starting up. Please read the documentation below:

https://docs.guidewire.com/self-managed/cc/1022/admin/admin/topics/c_nt2542362.html?hl=upgrades,upgrade,full

Comment: I should note that I was assuming you were trying this just to figure out the nuances of setting up a clustered environment. For everyday development work, each developer should have their own DB.